# iGraph vertical layout instead of horizontal

Tags: python, plotly, igraph

I am using the following code to plot a tree in python: https://plot.ly/python/tree-plots/#set-up-tree-with-igraph

This creates a tree visualized like this:

[image: tree graph horizontal layout]

However, I'd want to have the tree rendered in a vertical layout, like this:
[image: tree graph vertical layout]

Of course the numbers on each node should be rotated too.

Is this possible using igraph and plot.ly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's pretty easy actually, just swap all the values you pass to `x` and `y`, for example in the first trace instead of:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=Xe,
                   y=Ye,
                   mode='lines',
                   line=dict(color='rgb(210,210,210)', width=1),
                   hoverinfo='none'
                   ))
```

swap `x` and `y` so that it looks like this:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y=Xe,
                   x=Ye,
                   mode='lines',
                   line=dict(color='rgb(210,210,210)', width=1),
                   hoverinfo='none'
                   ))
```

and then do the same thing anywhere `x` and `y` are set (including in annotations).

Comment: Nice thanks! Is there a way to get the proper positioning given the tree.  In this case they hardcoded the position but is there a way to do it such that the positions are optimized?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but I think this warrants creating a separate SO Question :)

Comment: yes totally true.  It's basically a dynamic layout which is actually tricky.